# Populating a bootstrap styled table in shiny/shinydashboard with dataframe contents.

Tags: r, twitter-bootstrap, shiny, shinydashboard

I am having trouble figuring out how to dynamically create and populate rows to a bootstrap styled table based on an input dataframe.

Example... using the table (dt) below, I want to make a table in my ui that has 4 rows containing the data in the table.

I know how to do this by defining each line explicitly as I have done in the first row below, but I would really like to be able to do this dynamically as the number of rows will not always be the same.

Thanks for any help or suggestions!

```
## app.R ##
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

dt <- data.frame(1:4,1:4,1:4,1:4)
colnames(dt) <- c("Letter1","Letter2","Type1","Type2")

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    box(width = NULL,title = "simple table", uiOutput("lettertypetable"))
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$lettertypetable <- renderUI({
    tags$table(class = "table",
               tags$thead(tags$tr(
                 tags$th("Letter1"),
                 tags$th("letter2"),
                 tags$th("Type1"),
                 tags$th("Type2")
               )),
               tags$tbody(
                 tags$tr(
                   tags$td("alpha"),
                   tags$td("beta"),
                   tags$td("yello"),
                   tags$td("orange")
                 )
               )
    )
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, step 1, I recommend the DT package,

server:

`output$letterTypeTable <- DT::renderDataTable({dt})`

ui:

`DT::dataTableOutput('letterTypeTable')`

will basically do all the heavy lifting.

---

If simple table is truly required, you could try something absurdly hackish like this:

```
tags$table(class = "table",
    tags$thead(tags$tr(
        eval(parse(text = paste0('list(',paste0(paste0('tags$th("',names(dt),'")'),collapse=","),')'))))
    ),

    tags$tbody(as.list(apply(dt,1,function(x) tags$tr(eval(parse(text = paste0('list(',paste0(paste0('tags$th("',x,'")'),collapse=","),')')))))))
)
```

Comment: Thank you. I will give this solution a try :)

Answer (score 0):

Just for completeness, there is a much simpler solution to @Shape 's proposal:

Taking `ToothGrowth` as an example dataframe:

```
dt=ToothGrowth
```

we can keep the `lapply` but remove the  unneeded `eval(parse(...))`:

```
ui <- fluidPage( 
    tags$table(class = "table",
        tags$thead(tags$tr(
            lapply(names(dt), tags$th)
            )
        ),
        tags$tbody(
            apply(dt,1, function(...) tags$tr(lapply(..., tags$td)) )
        )
    ) 
)
server <- function(input, output) { }
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```